# React Post data onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, child-process

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {sds, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
> array instead.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
class Post extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={
            postData : "",
            postResult : " "
        }
    }
    onChangeHandler=(event)=>{
       var mydata= event.target.value;
       this.setState({postData:mydata})
    }
    onClickHandler=()=>{
        axios.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',this.state.postData)
            .then(response=>{
                this.setState({postResult:response.data})

            })
            .catch(error=>{
                alert("something wrong")
            })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.postResult}</p>
                <input onChange={this.onChangeHandler} type="text"/>
                <button onClick={this.onClickHandler}>Post</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Post;
```

Comment: You are rendering an object. Can you take a look state variable?

Comment: thanks for your response...
I don't understand.

Comment: Try `<p>{this.state.postResult}</p>` -> `<p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.postResult)}</p>`

Comment: this is working. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) your `response.data` will be an object following the structure:

```
{title: "myTitle", body: "myBody", id: 101}
```

this way `this.state.postResult` will be an object and you can't pass an object to render which results in the error experienced. Instead you can extract `title` and `body` from `postResult` for example:

```
render() {
    const { title, body } = this.state.postResult
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Title: {title}</h1>
            <p>Body: {body}</p>
            <input onChange={this.onChangeHandler} type="text"/>
            <button onClick={this.onClickHandler}>Post</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```